# ItemDeleting event receiver is not triggered for files when folder is deleted

Tags: event-receivers

I have item deleting event receiver on document library. I have folders and files in library.

- When I delete file event is triggered.
- When i delete folder event is triggered for folder but not for items
  inside folders.

How can I trigger event for files inside folder when i delete folder.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to activate delete event on all sub items. Rather you can handle that inside folder deleting handler.

Comment: @AmalHashim so what will be the best solution? 1) one you suggested or 2) do not allow user to delete folder. As we have logic in event receiver which will take long time if we go for approach 1.

Comment: Inside folder deleting event check if folder has files inside it, in that case call File Delete action (action mean what you want to do in case of file is deleted)

Comment: @AmalHashim But what if folder has thousands of item? Will this be the best solution in such situation?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve at the deleting event ?

Comment: @JayHell doing some processing to some other list. anyways I am planning to restrict user so that folders will not be deleted.